# FOSUserBundle: Why register uses the symfony forms whilst login renders it via html?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

As I was stydying the FOSUserBundle I noticed that the register form uses the `form_widget` and Symfony's form template as seen in `register_content.html.twig`:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

While the form fort login does not even bother to use the symfony's form template as seen in `logn_content.html.twig`:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    {% if csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
```

And I have the burning desire to learn why there is this differrence between the implementations of theese forms.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason can be that Symfony uses a different action that checks the credentials and thus Symfony does not use form validation and processing (data stored in an entity) the way that it does when using the formbuilder. So in this case you should use the formbuilder only to render the HTML which makes it a bit slower than rendering the HTML directly.

The formbuilder becomes a handy tool when you need to render forms that need validation and/or csrf protection or when you use an entity as formdata. But the use of Symfony's formbuilder is not mandatory and not always required. For example a formfield with only some Javascript actions that will not lead to a new (POST-)request and therefore never being processed on server-side does not need to use Symfony's formbuilder.